# Class already exists

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

In my project I am having 2 classes: 'Window' and 'Context'.
The class 'Window' instantiates a Window using WinAPI and everything works fine.
E.g. this code works as supposed:

```
Window win("Hello,", 600, 400);
Window win2("World!", 600, 400);
```

The class 'Context' creates an OpenGL 4.0 Context. In order to do so, 
it needs to create a temporary window and a temporary context to retreive all OpenGL 4.0 pointer, which in return are needed to create a OpenGL 4.0 context.
E.g. this code works as well:

```
Window win("Context", 600, 400);
Context ctx(win);
```

Everything works fine.

However, I am refactoring the code. Since a window can have only one context at all, I decided, that the window should manage the context, therefore it should instantiate and delete it itself. But this leads me to strange errors.

```
// Constructor of window
// We're at the end of the constructor
if(true == bOWnContext)
    pContext = internal::Context(*this);
}; // Constructor ends here
```

When executing the application I get an exception/error: "Class already registered."
This is strange since following code works for me:

```
Window winA(...);
Window winB(...);
// or
Context ctx(winA);
// This works like a charm
```

Some collegue suggested, I should register the window class only once,
so I tried the following in the constructor:

```
    static bool bRegistered = false;
    if(false == bRegistered){
    WNDCLASSEX  wc      = {};
    wc.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hInstance        = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = internal::WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName    = pTitle;
    wc.style            = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;

    if(0 == RegisterClassEx(&wc)){
        //
        //  The exception class will contain the error code and
        //  a error discription.
        //
        std::error_code err_code(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
        throw std::system_error(err_code);
    }
    bRegistered = true;
    }
```

However, this gives me another error "Cannot find window class."

Can somebody enlighten me, why my code is not working?

Comment: Your window class has no class name. It cannot be referenced. Not sure what window class name you provide in your call to `CreateWindow[Ex]`. That `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` is a bug waiting to happen as well, as soon as you compile the code into a DLL. At any rate, the code you provided is not the place where class registration fails with an *"already registered"* error message.

Comment: The window class name equals the name of the window I provide in the constructor. Now I see why the 'Cannot find window class' error appears.
What is wrong about GetModuleHandle(nullptr)? I am already compiling it into a DLL and it works. The only thing that fails is, if I create a new window inside the other window.

Comment: Oh, you are right, your are providing a class name. What's wrong about `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)`: It returns the module handle to the EXE, not the DLL. But it is the DLL that implements the window procedure. The all-encompassing solution to finding the correct module handle: [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using the HINSTANCE of the module now. As suggested in the link. 
Sadly this doesn't fix me problem :(

Comment: Sir, your previous comment gave me an idea and it works like charm now. Thanks, mate!

Comment: If you have a solution please post it as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is, that the class is being registered multiple times. My first solution to this problem was trying to reference a class, that probably didn't exist. 
My working solution creates a class and memorizes it's reference the following way:

```
    static const char*    pcClassName;
    if(nullptr == pcClassName){
        WNDCLASSEX  wc      = {};
        wc.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.hInstance        = ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase);
        wc.lpfnWndProc      = internal::WndProc;
        wc.lpszClassName    = pTitle;
        wc.style            = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;

        if(0 == RegisterClassEx(&wc)){
            //
            //  The exception class will contain the error code and
            //  a error description.
            //
            std::error_code err_code(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
            throw std::system_error(err_code);
        }
        pcClassName = pTitle;
    }
```

The name of the class is used to refer to the window class later in the actual creation of the window. E.g. like this:

```
    pHandle->handle = CreateWindowEx(
        bFullscreen ? WS_EX_APPWINDOW : NULL,
        pcClassName,
        pTitle,
        bFullscreen ? WS_POPUP : WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // NOTE: Perhaps I'll create a window config struct?
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2,
        clientArea.right    - clientArea.left,
        clientArea.bottom   - clientArea.top,
        nullptr,    // We're not having a parent window
        nullptr,    // nor a win32 menu.
        ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase),
        pHandle    // Is needed for the router 'WndProc'.
    );
```

However, since I am compiling this code into a DLL, I used @IInspectable solution on retrieving the right 'HINSTANCE'.
For further details checkout his comment.

*__ImageBase* is defined as following:

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're starting of a wrong assumption:

> … Since a window can have only one context at all, …

Nope.

There can be an arbitrary number of contexts and in fact contexts are not tied to a particular window.

As long as the pixelformat of the window matches that of a context you can make the context current on the window. And if you have several threads you can make different context current on the *same* window at the same time (given the contexts are compatible with the window's pixelformat).

Comment: Oh, that's probably a design issue. I thought a Context is tied a DC.

Comment: @Julien: It is. But there can be an arbitrary number of device contexts for every window.

Comment: Isn't there only one per Window, considering that the Window Class defined 'CS_OWNDC'?

Comment: @Julien: A window has a primary DC but you can create additional references to that at any time. For example BeginPaint, EndPaint does exactly that. More importantly Device Contexts are something different than OpenGL render contexts. So you can have multiple DCs per window (all sharing the windows pixelformat) and you can have multiple OpenGL render contexts which can be bound and rebound arbitrarily because they're not tied to a particular window or DC.

Comment: @Julien: The `CS_OWNDC` class style is only an optimization: It requests that the window manager never purges a window's DC with this class style from its DC cache. So whenever you call `GetDC` or `BeginPaint` for this window you get the same DC. That doesn't mean that a window - in general - cannot be associated with more than one DC.